# 'const float' value different than 'float' when casting to 'int' in C#

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-bug

Can any of you explain why does this happen?

```
static void Main()
{
    const float xScaleStart = 0.5f;
    const float xScaleStop = 4.0f;
    const float xScaleInterval = 0.1f;
    const float xScaleAmplitude = xScaleStop - xScaleStart;

    const float xScaleSizeC = xScaleAmplitude / xScaleInterval;

    float xScaleSize = xScaleAmplitude / xScaleInterval;

    Console.WriteLine(">const float {0}, (int){1}", xScaleSizeC, (int)xScaleSizeC);

    Console.WriteLine(">      float {0}, (int){1}", xScaleSize, (int)xScaleSize);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
>const float 35, (int)34
>      float 35, (int)35
```

I know that the binary representation of 0.1 is actually 0.09999990463256835937, though why does this happen using 'const float' and not with 'float'? Is this considered a compiler bug?

For the record, the code compiles into:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float xScaleSize = 35f;
    Console.WriteLine(">const float {0}, (int){1}", 35f, 34);
    Console.WriteLine(">      float {0}, (int){1}", xScaleSize, (int)xScaleSize);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ulugbek for the compiled code

Comment: I will confirm that this does not always happen. Using monodevelop and Unity3d (runs a flavor of mono) both results are 35.

Comment: maybe a duplicate, or at least related: [Why differs floating-point precision in C# when separated by parantheses and when separated by statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491161/why-differs-floating-point-precision-in-c-sharp-when-separated-by-parantheses-an)

Comment: Related, especially as the answer is the same: [Get float constant to be the same the runtime result (and VB.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19593234/256431)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "Why" of this will basically boil down to the fact that frequently, when working with `float` data, an internal representation may be used that has more precision than is specified for `float` or `double`. This is explicitly catered for in the Virtual Execution System (VES) Spec (section 12 of [Partition I](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/3/733AD403-90B2-4064-A81E-01035A7FE13C/MS%20Partition%20I.pdf)):

> floating-point numbers are represented using an internal floating-point
>   type. In each such instance, the nominal type of the variable or expression is either `float32` or `float64`, but its
>   value can be represented internally with additional range and/or precision

And then later we have:

> The use of an internal representation that is wider than `float32` or `float64` can cause differences in
>   computational results when a developer makes seemingly unrelated modifications to their code, the result of
>   which can be that a value is spilled from the internal representation (e.g., in a register) to a location on the
>   stack.

Now, according to the [C# language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7029):

> The compile-time evaluation of constant expressions uses the same rules as run-time evaluation of non-constant expressions, except that where run-time evaluation would have thrown an exception, compile-time evaluation causes a compile-time error to occur.

But as we observe above, the rules actually allow more precision to be used at times, and when this enhanced precision is used isn't actually under our direct control.

---

And obviously, in different circumstances, the results could have been precisely the opposite of what you observed - the compiler may have dropped to lower precision and the runtime could have maintained higher precision instead.

Comment: Also relevant from the C# spec: *Floating-point operations may be performed with higher precision than the result type of the operation. For example, some hardware architectures support an “extended” or “long double” floating-point type with greater range and precision than the double type, and implicitly perform all floating-point operations using this higher precision type.* `xScaleSizeC` is actually `34.99999947845936532075938885100185871124267578125` (at least on my hardware), and that explains why it gets truncated to `34` when cast to `int`.

Comment: @sloth - yes, that looks like the "translation" of the VES specification into C# terms. I went with the VES one just because I'm more familiar with it.

Comment: I can see xScaleSizeC as 35f in the decompiled code with dotPeek. I just get that value if I have it as double...

Comment: @joaojose Have a look at [this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) class which will give you a string representation of the exact decimal value of `xScaleSizeC`.

Comment: @sloth I get your answer and you are right, though I don't get why does the compiler "rounds" a 34.9999 float to 35f?

Comment: @joaojose A float has only a 7-digit precision. `34.9999` is fine and can be represented, also `34.99999`. But `34,9999994784594` can't be represented using only 32-bits, so it gets rounded to nearest, which is `35.00000`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say this is a duplicate question since in here --> [Eric Postpischil comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066385/different-results-when-casting-int-and-const-int-to-float)

explained something very similar regarding int's and const int's.

The main idea is that the division of two constants calculated by the compiler before generating the code and not in run-time, BUT in this specific case whenever the compiler does this it performs the calculations in **double** format. Thus the xScaleSizeC is basically equals 34.9999... so when it getting cast in run-time to int it becomes 34.

Comment: @joaojose as explained in Damiens answer, the calculation of `xScaleSizeC` at hardware level is done with more precision than .Net's `float` type can represent. So the const `xScaleSizeC` is actually `34.999999478...`, and when forced into .Net's `float` type, you lose the precision and the value gets rounded to `35`, and when cast into `int`, the decimal values get truncated, resulting in `34`. You can see it yourself when using a type with higher precision, like `double`: `xScaleSizeC` won't get rounded up and is represented by `34.999999478...`.